# Why does Apache fail to restart after editing the conf file?

Tags: svn, apache2, bitnami

I have the Bitnami Ruby Stack with the Redmine module installed on Windows Server 2003. When I add:

```
<Location /svn/repo1>
    DAV svn
    SVNPAth "D:/Repositories/repo1"
</Location>
```

to the end of the

> D:\Program Files\BitNami RubyStack\apache2\conf\httpd.conf

file, Apache fails to restart.

Comment: You will need to consult the Apache error_log to find out what is going wrong.  Note that unless it is a typo above, you have `SVNPAth` instead of `SVNPath`, though I don't think that should cause Apache to choke.

Comment: The error log contained a statement that a file in apache2/htdocs/svn was missing. It turned out that two of the required svn modules were not in the apache2/modules folder. I copied them from the subversion folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use SVN in Apache, you must load needed DAV-modules before. Do you have:

```
LoadModule .../mod_dav.so
LoadModule .../mod_dav_svn.so
```

in httpd.conf or recompiled Apache with these *static modules*?

Be sure that these two modules and the other modules mentioned in the subversion README.txt are in the apache2/modules folder. You can copy them from the subversion folder.

Recommendation to inspect error.log is still valid.

Comment: I checked the error log. It said that a file in apache2/htdocs/svn was missing. I found out that two svn modules were not in the apache2/modules folder. They were however in the subversion folder. I copied them into the modules folder. It works now. The BitNami guys were supposed to make sure that these modules are there already.

Comment: @GeoffreyVanWyk - anyway: 1. fix location, it have to be `<Location /svn/>` 2. if you don't use site-root, `  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/svn$
  RewriteRule ^(.*/svn)$ %1/ [R=301,L]` inside `<Directory />` will be useful 3. Move on start to ` SVNListParentPath on
  SVNParentPath "..."` seems as good idea